# How to get the status of sharing after clicking PlusOneButton in Android

Tags: android, google-plus-one

I am trying to get status if user has shared, pressed OK or pressed cancel the PlusOneButton share dialog. I tried to find the solution but didn't get any. When I cancel the share dialog, the progress bar keeps loading over the PlusOneButton. I need to get all the status to maintain the status into the application. below is the code I used.

```
PlusOneButton plusButton = (PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);
// if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
plusButton.initialize("APP_URL", PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);

plusButton.setOnPlusOneClickListener(new PlusOneButton.OnPlusOneClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlusOneClick(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```